# Problem Viewing PDF in Browser

Tags: php, pdf, view

I have a link in my page :

```
<a href="sharedfiles/general.pdf"> View PDF</a>
```

The problem is that when the link is clicked, Instead of viewing the content of the file in the browser, the file is downloaded .

Any ideas what's wrong?

ps : I have Mozilla FireFox 3.6 & Adobe Reader Installed

Comment: Post the headers being sent.  You can get these from [LiveHttpHeaders](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829/).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use the correct mime type (application/pdf), and the `Content-Disposition: inline` header.

Answer (score 0):

Check your webserver is providing the correct MIME type for the response - it should be application/pdf